# HTML5 video tag doesn't work on iPhone/Safari (SFCC)

Tags: html5, commerce-cloud, video, safari

I'm struggling with this: HTML5 video tag is not working on iPhone (Safari).

This is my code:

```
<video class="video" controls="" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" preload="auto">
   <source src="${pdict.video_url}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Has anyone faced this problem before in SFCC?

Comment: mp4 is the container format for the video, but arguably the more important thing to know is _which codec was used to encode the video_. That, and the version of Safari. Cursory searching reveals that Safari needs you to use (an implementation of) the H264 codec (Safari 3.2+) or H265 codec (Safari 11+). Things like VLC media player, FFMpeg, or Mediainfo can tell you which codec was used to make a video file.

Answer (score 1):

Video tag is working fine with html5 in SFCC on apple devices.

Here is the example from live site, which is loading video correctly. FYI, we have used Video.js

```
<video id="html5" class="vjs-tech" preload="auto" poster="https://images.example.com/is/image/H1_image?fit=constrain,1&amp;wid=664&amp;hei=664" data-setup="{}" style="max-width:100%" src="https://images.example.com/is/content/H1_1" controls="">
```

Hope this might help you.
Thanks,
A

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing video tag with iframe tag

Code which I  used

```
<apex:page >   
<video style="border:1px solid red; background-color: red; position:absolute;" controls="true" >
    <source src="{!$Resource.VideoDemo}" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>  </apex:page>
```

By

```
<apex:page >   
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="{!$Resource.VideoDemo}" frameborder="0"></iframe></apex:page>
```